# Writing a CMakeLists.txt for ROS

Tags: cmake, ros

I am new to ROS (Indigo), and I want to write a C++ program to use the MoveIt! package.

However, I am confused as to what I need to have in my CMakeLists.txt file, such that the header and library files can be found.

For example, here is the file so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

project(MicoMoveIt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

file(GLOB srcs *.cpp)

include_directories(/opt/ros/indigo/include)

link_directories(/opt/ros/indigo/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${srcs})
```

And my main.cpp file is:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>

int main()
{
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("right_arm");
    return 0;
}
```

But compiling this gives me the error:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/robot_model/joint_model.h:47: error: Eigen/Geometry: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Geometry>
                          ^
```

So, I need to specify where to find these Eigen header files. But given that Eigen is a dependency of MoveIt!, then I shouldn't have to manually include all these header file directories.

How should I be writing the CMakeLists.txt file so that all header and library directories of dependencies are included?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this changes:

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(<project_name>)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  <other_packages_you_need>
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(BINNAME <executable_name>)
set(SOURCES <cpp_source_files>)

add_executable (${BINNAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${BINNAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

The key factor for your problem is the inclusion of package `moveit_ros_planning_interface` in the `find_package()` directive. Everytime you have to build some code, you have to add *every* package dependancies to your project (in this case you need the moveit interface package). Notice that the `package.xml` file plays a crucial role too.

Lastly you have to tell the linker to retrieve and link the libraries you are using in your project. To do so use `target_link_libraries()` and the useful `catkin_LIBRARIES` variable which almost does what you expected (you could manually add libraries, but it could be messy in big projects).

Have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/) for more info.

**EDIT:** in this case you do not need the `link_directories()` directive, which has to be used only when the linker has to know where to retrieve the external library.

Comment: One thing to add: ROS comes with the tool `catkin_create_pkg` which should be used to create new packages (it automatically generates a basic CMakeLists.txt with lots of comments). See also the [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).